# error 2136 in ms access-open form or report in design view

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form that acts as a subform in one case and as a dialog box in another. To do this I have used a boolean. When its true I want the form to open as a dialog. For this I have used the following statement inside the `if` condition:

`Me.Borderstyle=3`

But on running the application it gives error 2136 that says:

> open the form or report in design view

Debugging leads me to the line with the borderstyle code.

What could be the reason? Is it not possible to set borderstyle through code?
The form works fine if i comment this part... it's just that it's not visually appealing if it doesn't look like a dialog.The code is as below:

```
  Private Sub Form_Load()
    If chk = True Then
    WindowS Me, 2, 2, 90, 70
    Me.first.Locked = True
    Me.second.Locked = True
    Me.BorderStyle = 3
    Else

       WindowS Me ' resize window and controls to current screen resolution
       Me.cmdCLOSE.Visible = False
    End If
    End Sub
```

Apppreciate the help.

Comment: Please post the full VBA sub or function containing `Me.Borderstyle=3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear - you can't set this property in Form view, only in Design view.

For some reason this information got lost in the help file for `Form.Borderstyle` - it was present in older versions, as [quoted here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=200412):

> From the Access 97 VBA helpfile on the BorderStyle property:
>   "You can set the BorderStyle property for a form **only in form Design view** by using the form's property sheet, a macro, or Visual Basic."

It's the same for e.g. the `Form.CloseButton` property, here the [help file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823184.aspx) mentions it.

IMO it makes sense that you can't change structural form properties like these when the form is open.

---

As to your requirement:

> I have a form that acts as a subform in one case and as a dialog box in another.

Subforms don't have a border anyway, so why not simply set the border style to "Dialog" and leave it at that?

Comment: Hi andre ...thank u for ur response...should have thot of the same...works perfectly now ....appreciate the help